# How to get details using In Operator

Tags: mysql

I have got two tables video_details and video_tag .
I am trying to get the video_details data for which belong to particualr tag id

This is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video_details` (
  `video_id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Auto Generated key',
  `video_name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `video_file` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `how_to_video` varchar(100) default NULL COMMENT 'information video',
  `video_desc` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `video_created_date` timestamp NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `video_status` tinyint(1) default NULL COMMENT '0-->video will not be displayed.,1-->video will be displayed ',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`video_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=382 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video_tag` (
  `video_id` int(6) default NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) default NULL,
  KEY `FK__tag_details` (`tag_id`),
  KEY `FK__video_details` (`video_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK__video_details` FOREIGN KEY (`video_id`) REFERENCES `video_details` (`video_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

corresponding sql fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74b210

I have tried it this way

```
select vt.video_id , vd.video_name from video_tag vt , video_details vd 
where vt.tag_id in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use join

```
SELECT vt.video_id , vd.video_name 
FROM video_tag vt 
LEFT JOIN video_details vd on vd.video_id = vt.video_id
WHERE vt.tag_id in (1,2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , this answers my question perfectly , is it also possible to write query in case for tag_id = 1 OR 2 ?? similarly

Comment: not sure what do you mean, IN works same as OR,
tag_id in (1,2) is the same as  (tag_id = 1 OR tag_id = 2)